# How to write a compare function in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

for example, I want to check whether a is greater than b, here is a my code

```
def gt(a:Any,b:Any):Boolean = a match{
  case a:Ordered[Any] => (a compareTo b ) > 0
  case _ => false
}
```

however, there's more accurate way to implement this? Because the compiler give a warning:

```
<console>:8: warning: non-variable type argument Any in type pattern Comparable[Any] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
         case a:Comparable[Any] => (a compareTo b ) > 0
```

### update

the implicit view should do the work,but I what I wanna do is have a function
with the parameter (a:Any,b:Any), not type parameter. In java, the code maybe like this, but I don't know how to implement it in  Scala way

```
public static boolean gt(Object a, Object b){
    if(a instanceof Comparable && b.getClass() == a.getClass() ){
        return ((Comparable) a).compareTo(b) > 0;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

update again,I made a workable solution already, but i know it not the best way,and I will leave this question open

```
def ls(a: Any, b: Any): Boolean = {
  a match {
    case (a: Comparable[Any]) => (a compareTo b) < 0
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Comment: because i wanna to pass the GT function as a parameter to another function. what I expect GT to do is to compare A and B where they could compare, return false when A and B could not compare to each other,for example, A = 1 and B = "1"

Answer (score 4):

Your method will return incorrectly for some very basic cases (e.g. `gt(2,1)`).  You're probably looking for:

```
def gt[T <% Ordered[T]](a:T, b:T) = a > b
```

In your example, you avoid specifying a generic parameter (the parameter `T`).  This guarantees that the arguments to the function are of the same type, thereby attaining some type safety.

You want that type parameter to be ordered.  The way this is implemented in Scala is the `Ordered` trait, which takes a self type as a generic parameter.

The syntax `<%` means that there needs to be an implicit conversion  from `T` to `Ordered[T]` (called an *view bound* type parameter).  This is true for all the standard ordered types in Scala (e.g. `Int`, `Char`, etc.).  Without this view bound, the compiler can't know that the generic parameter is necessary ordered.

Finally, `Ordered` has a `>` function on it, so you don't need to use `compareTo`, since it is already implemented.

You can read more about implicit views in the docs [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/views.html).
You can read more about `Ordered` in the docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.math.Ordered).

Comment: thanks a lot, that's really helpful. but what if a wanna the function return false when i call gt(5,"4")?

Comment: @JadeTang That's something that is generally avoided in Scala.  You should generally know the types of your arguments.  It is rare that you need a variable of type `Any`, and might be indicative of weak design, or at least unidiomatic Scala code.    Also, it looks like your current solution throws an error right now for even basic cases like `ls(1, "1")`.

Comment: @JadeTang Also, your update changes the character of the question, and I think it should be moved to a new question.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I tired to redesign my code, and I rephrase my question to a new one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180212/scala-pass-type-parameter-function-as-a-parameter-of-another-function