# scala pass type parameter function as a parameter of another function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose,I have a function, take two values and a function as parameters.

```
def ls[S](a: S, b: S)(implicit evl: S => Ordered[S]): Boolean = a < b
def myfunction[T](a: T, b: T, f:(T,T)=>Boolean) = {

  if (f(a, b)) {
    println("is ok")
  }
  else {
    println("not ok")
  }
}

myfunction(1, 2, ls)
```

the IDE don't give any error message,but when I try to compile and run,the compliter give this message:

```
    Error:(14, 19) No implicit view available from S => Ordered[S].
myfunction(1, 2, ls);}
                 ^
```

So,is there a way to pass type parameter function as a parameter of another function ?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly this works:

```
myfunction[Int](1, 2, ls)
myfunction(1, 2, ls[Int])
```

From my understanding the Scala compiler tries to resolve type `T` of `myfunction`.

It finds first and second argument and is happy to assign it to `Int` (or anything that is its supertype) as the best match.

But the third argument says that it can get anything as a parameter! Then the Scala compiler must comply and decides that `T` will be `Any`. Which causes `S` be of type `Any` and there is no implicit view `Any => Ordered[Any]`

You must not think of `myfunction` as defining a type for `ls` but rather `ls` defining what type `T` can be.

Which is why this will work as you will already know what type of `f` you want:

```
def myfunction[T](a: T, b: T)(f:(T,T)=>Boolean) = {
...
}
myfunction(1, 2)(ls)
```